# how to get data from the WTO API in R

Tags: r

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

headers = c(
  # Request headers
  'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' = '{subscription key}'
)

params = list()

# Request parameters
params['countries[]'] = '{array}'


resp <- GET(paste0("https://api.wto.org/tfad/transparency/procedures_contacts_single_window?"

               , paste0(names(params),'=',params,collapse = "&")),

        add_headers(headers))

if(!http_error(resp)){    
  jsonRespText<-fromJSON(rawToChar(content(resp,encoding = 'UTF-8')))$Dataset

  jsonRespText

}else{
  stop('Error in Response')
}
```

I don't know how to get response from an API in R. I have executed this code but the server is not responding...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good that you included code, that helps us help you. Please also notice some of the edits I made to your question. Stack is a little different than a forum in that you won't have to include many extraneous comments but the more detail you put into the actual explanation of your programming question the better.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the value of the `resp` object after running your code you'll notice a status code:

```
> resp
Response [https://tfadatabase.org/api/transparency/procedures_contacts_single_window?countries[]=%7Barray%7D]
  Date: 2020-04-17 19:25
  Status: 422
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 77 B
```

So the server actually *did* respond, it just didn't give you what you were hoping for. In the API documentation we can [look up](https://apiportal.wto.org/docs/services/tfad/operations/get-transparency-procedures_contacts_single_window) this code:

> 422 Unprocessable Entity
>
> If a member cannot be found, or the request parameters are poorly
>   formed.

So I just went to the Query Builder and looked for a valid request URL and updated the code. It ran fine - i.e. Status 200.

This was the URL I used in the code:

`https://api.wto.org/timeseries/v1/data?i=TP_A_0100&r=000&fmt=json&mode=full&lang=1&meta=false`

and the value of `resp` was

```
  Date: 2020-04-17 19:30
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 88 B
```

I cut out the subscription key in my results above. You can find the Query Builder [here](https://apiportal.wto.org/query-builder). Incidentally, in the Query Builder it automatically includes the subscription key and other "header" info in the URL. You can either remove that first and re-add it in your code, or just change your code to run `GET()` directly on their version of the URL.